# Elixir - atom which doesnt start with upper case

Tags: erlang, elixir

In elixir, atoms should start with `:`, so why even all literals which starts with upper case are treated as atoms too?

```
IO.puts is_atom(Foo) # true, why????
IO.puts is_atom(foo) # error undefined function
IO.puts is_atom(:foo) # true
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As you can see [here](http://elixir-lang.org/crash-course.html#data_types), identifiers that start with uppercase letters are treated as atom aliases. In your case, `Foo` is an alias of `:'Elixir.Foo'` which is an atom.

Comment: FYI: module names are atoms in Erlang VM. So e.g. you can call function sleep/1 from module :timer this way in Elixir: :timer.sleep(1000).
Elixir modules are atoms starting with a capital letter and prefix "Elixir" is automatically added. So from Erlang you would call e.g. 'Elixir.Supervisor':start_link(...) and in Elixir: Supervisor.start_link(...)